# Simple vue template conditional rendering issue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I am just getting started with view but have run into this frustrating problem. I have this template which uses `v-if` and `v-else` in the simplest possible way. However, the template will not load on the page. That is, neither the `v-if` nor the `v-else` div is displayed regardless of what value `isLoggedIn` has set in the `data` function.

I have looked around for solutions but nothing has worked. The template couldn't be any more straight forward so I am not sure how to proceed with debugging it.

Interestingly, the component is imported into the main `App.vue` as `<Login/>` shows up in the Components tab of the Vue developer tools console. I have no idea why the conditional rendering is not working on the page. Any help much appreciated.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-if="isLoggedIn">  
     <p>Logged in: {{isLoggedIn}}</p>

    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <p>You are not logged in</p>
    <div>
  </div>
</template>



<script>

export default {
  name: "Login",
  data() {
    return { isLoggedIn: true };

  },
  methods: {}
   
};
</script>
```

Here is the `App.vue` file. Again it is super simple. I have also tried removing the `Record` component completely but it still doesn't work.

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <Login />
    <Record />
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import Login from "./components/Login.vue";
import Record from "./components/Record.vue";
export default { name: "App", components: { Login, Record } };
</script>
```

Comment: could you post the codes for `App.vue`? so that we will see how you used `Login` component. And any error in the console? if yes, post it out as well.

Comment: I just updated my question with the `App.vue` code. As you can see there is not much to it. There are no errors in the console. Thanks!

Comment: when you put another content instead of divs containing `v-if` and `v-else` does it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a small typo. The `div` of `v-else` is not closed:

```
<div>
    <div v-if="isLoggedIn">  
     <p>Logged in: {{isLoggedIn}}</p>

    </div>

    <div v-else>
      <p>You are not logged in</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

This is preventing `Vue` from applying the conditionals.

Comment: Oh my, what a silly error. I thought it was probably something stupid simple that was staring me in the face. Thanks a million!

Comment: @mikeym we've all faced such issues :) you are welcome.

Comment: Thanks. That is very reassuring!